# How can I adjust PDO fetchAll() to set the keys to the array created to match table names in a multi table query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am querying a column in three identically structured tables via UNION ALL

```
 $sql="
(SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 IN ('a','b','c') and col3 IS NOT NULL)
UNION ALL
(SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col2 IN ('a','b','c') and col3 IS NOT NULL)
UNION ALL
(SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col2 IN ('a','b','c')  and col3 IS NOT NULL)
";
```

I then use PDO to prepare that statement and execute it

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();   
$var = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My problem is that the array produced: $var, uses integer keys andsplits each result into a sub array. I need the results from each table to be in their own sub array, preferably with the table name as the key.

So currently:

`print_r($var)`; gives:

```
Array 
    (
    [0] => Array ( [col1] => asd) 
    [1] => Array ( [col1] => sdf) 
    [2] => Array ( [col1] => dfg) 
    [3] => Array ( [col1] => fgh)
    )
```

I would like:

```
Array 
   (
[table1] => Array 
    (
     [0] => Array ( [col1] => asd) 
     [1] => Array ( [col1] => sdf) 
    )

[table2] => Array 
    (
     [0] => Array ( [col1] => asd)      
    )

[table3] => Array 
    (
     [0] => Array ( [col1] => asd)      
    )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a single query, but you could use the AS keyword to prefix the column names with their corresponding table names, after that you would just need to preprocess the array to come up with something similar to your specification.